# Drip irrigation for farming tomatoes?

Tags: tomatoes, drip-system

My uncle just starting farming tomatoes. For irrigation he used to mix chemicals in water and irrigate the farm for 1 to 2 hour's 2 times a day, but the results were not good. Most of the plants died and the rest didn't give even 25% of the normal amount of tomatoes. So if any one can help suggesting if there is a problem in the drip irrigation system or anything else.

Pipes where laid in the following manner; one main pipe running perpendicular to lines of plants and one pipe going in each line with holes in it at every plant.
If anyone can suggest me the correct way to configure it for a plantation of tomatoes using drip irrigation, it would help me.

Comment: What sort of soil? Weather? Sounds like he probably over watered the plants.

Comment: no he actually consulted the local expert for the duration and amount of water to be given to the plant's. Weather was a little bit cold and no rain . I don't know about the soil

Answer (score 5):

Plants can be affected by so many different things from disease, over/under fertilization, weather, humidity, air flow, etc., and you haven't provided enough information for anyone to give any useful feedback.

What part of the world were the tomatoes planted? Different areas have different problems. Country, region, city...

What "chemicals" were used in the water? Was it bleach? That would definitely kill the plants :)

What was previously grown in that area? Was it previously uncultivated? Were there tomatoes? Beets? Corn? Grass? Tomatoes in particular can benefit from proper crop rotation.

What's the soil like? Send samples to a lab. In the US a local university extension office can provide all sorts of tests on the soil to let you know what needs to be improved and how. Make sure you indicate what you plan to grow when you submit samples to get the right kind of recommendations.

What actually killed the plants? Was it disease? Was it insects? Was it improper feeding or watering? Was it from lack of sunlight? Did you try and grow the tomatoes on a football field and they were trampled to death? What symptoms did they exhibit? Lots of extension offices can also analyze the plants and determine what's wrong with them and can identify the pathogens that are affecting it. They'll be able to provide guidance as to what you can do to help.

I don't know who you're "local expert" is but I would go through legitimate university extension offices and labs (not their Master Gardeners) to get a good prognosis. Especially if I were trying to raise tomatoes to sell which sounds like what your uncle is doing based on your language.

Answer (score 1):

Could have been a mix of chemicals where a bit too strong- always under feed and what i do is put a lump of well rotted manure under the soil where the plant is to be planted- this acts as a reservoir for moisture (only water in the evening)and a food store, i only start feeding after the first truss has set and remove all dead leaves when they turn yellow- beware of blight as this can kill all your plants within a day!
Misting and slightly knocking the plants can help with pollenation, there are varieties that are resistant to deseases but don't have much flavour... if grown under cover they must have shading on the windows to avoid sun burn(depends on which direction your facing with afternoon sun) and water the floors to add humidity to the air or the leaves will curl up- its all about prevention with tomatoes- make them happy and they will grow well plus a good summer to ripen them off too.